# Catalog URL Rewrites error in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4, ecommerce-tracking

I am getting an error "`An error occurred while saving the URL rewrite`" in admin panel `system -> Index manager -> Catalog URL Rewrites -> REINDEX REQUIRED`. How can I fix this?

Comment: what error it shows. can you plz share the screen

Comment: did you tried to do re-index it? What error coming when you re-index data?

Comment: am getting this message "An error occurred while saving the URL rewrite"

Comment: can you check  exception.log if any specific error in that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sometimes while doing a Reindex in the Admin Panel you will get the error**

> An error occurred while saving the URL rewrite.

Now, while there are numerous fixes to this issue, I found one that I felt best addressed the issue and corrected it quickly with minimal effort.

If you tried to reindex any of the other index’s past Catalog URL Rewrites, those will fail as well, but do not confuse those not indexing with the Catalog URL Rewrite. If you try to reindex those separately they will still work as the issue only lies with Catalog URL Rewrites.

Now to fix this issue you will need to truncate your core_url_rewrite table.

Just run the following mysql query

```
 TRUNCATE core_url_rewrite;
```

To check that it worked run this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM core_url_rewrite;
```

it should come back that it is 0.

Now go into the admin panel and reindex your Catalog URL Rewrites. At this point, it should work without an error.

If you want to be extra-sure it worked, you can go back to your Terminal or SVN and go back to the sql table and run the

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM core_url_rewrite;
```

This time it should return a much higher number then 0.

Comment: Good job.@Supravat .one thing remember.. delete records from `core_url_rewrite`. will create issue in seo. if product urls & categories urls  crawl in seo

Answer (score 0):

**The following will reindex each index.**

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);
    $process->reindexAll();
}
```

You could also call the function `getProcessByCode` as follows:

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
$process->reindexAll();
```